# How to make table less cramped

Tags: tables, calculations, etoolbox

I have a table which is defined using `etoolbox` but I'm not sure how to make it look less cramped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*\mytable{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \foreach \j in {1,...,6}{
        \ADD{\i}{\j}\sum
        \FRACTIONSIMPLIFY{\sum}{35}\num\div
        \xappto\mytable{
            $(\i,\j)\rightarrow\frac\num\div$
        }
    }
    \gappto\mytable{\\}
}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    \mytable
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: B. t.w., I tried your code with `\mfrac` or `\dfrac` in the place of `\frac`, and there's an error message. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment and creates 6 separate left-aligned columns whose contents are automatically in display-math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator,pgffor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{array} % <-- new
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\mytable{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \foreach \j in {1,...,6}{
        \ADD{\i}{\j}\sum
        \FRACTIONSIMPLIFY{\sum}{35}\num\div
        \xappto\mytable{
            (\i,\j)\to\frac{\num}{\div}& % note: no $-symbols necessary
        }
    }
    \gappto\mytable{\\}
}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.25}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{>{\displaystyle}l} l @{}}
    \mytable
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Some explanations:

- The opening and closing `@{}` particles mean, "no whitespace padding" (at the left- and right-hand edges). (These particles are, strictly speaking, optional. However, I think it's nice to provide them.)
- `*{6}{>{\displaystyle}l}` means, "create 6 columns of type `>{\displaystyle}l`", i.e., left-aligned columns whose cells are automatically in display-style math mode. This is useful because `\frac` will then generate "large" fractions.
- The final `l`-type column is a "dummy" column. Its contents are always going to be empty; it's necessary, though, to specify a 7th column, as the `(\i,\j)\to\frac{\num}{\div}&` directive inserts a column divider, `&`, at the end of each output string. Since there are 6 instances of `&`, one must set up 7 (not 6) columns.

Answer (score 12):

Experiment with Mico's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433406/16967): The fractions can be made less ragged, if the fraction bars have equal lengths. All numerators and denominators have one or two digits. The macro `\mytwofrac` extends the numerator and/or denominator, if there is only one digit. The following example assumes non-proportional widths for the digits and that the width of a digit is 0.5em (for simplicity).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator,pgffor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{array} % <-- new
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\mytwofrac}[2]{%
  \frac
  {\ifnum#1<10 \kern.25em#1\kern.25em\else#1\fi}%
  {\ifnum#2<10 \kern.25em#2\kern.25em\else#2\fi}%
}

\newcommand*\mytable{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \foreach \j in {1,...,6}{
        \ADD{\i}{\j}\sum
        \FRACTIONSIMPLIFY{\sum}{35}\num\div
        \xappto\mytable{
            (\i,\j)\to\mytwofrac{\num}{\div}&
        }
    }
    \gappto\mytable{\\}
}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.25}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{>{\displaystyle}l} l @{}}
    \mytable
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution with `cellspace`, which lets you define *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with sprefixezd with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\mytable{}
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \foreach \j in {1,...,6}{
        \ADD{\i}{\j}\sum
        \FRACTIONSIMPLIFY{\sum}{35}\num\div
        \xappto\mytable{
            $(\i,\j)\rightarrow\frac\num\div$
        }
    }
    \gappto\mytable{\\}
}

\begin{tabular}{Sc}
    \mytable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here's a separate, LuaLaTeX-based (or LuaJITLaTeX-based) answer. It sets up several Lua functions which do all the work, including the job of simplifying fractional expressions such as `\frac{10}{35}` and `\frac{7}{35}` to `\frac{2}{7}` and `\frac{1}{5}`, respectively. Thus, the answer does *not* require the `pgffor`, `calculator`, and `etoolbox` packages.

Moreover, the `array` environment now consists of just 6 columns, i.e., the solution doesn't require a 7th, dummy column (as was the case in some of the earlier answers). Separately, the code also employs a simplified form of the `\mytwofrac` macro proposed in [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433410/5001).

Since the output looks exactly as the one in Heiko's answer, I'm posting just the code, without a screenshot.

First, the LaTeX code.

```
% !TEX TS-program = luajitlatex  % or: !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} % left-aligned & displaystyle math mode
\newcommand{\mytwofrac}[2]{% cf. Heiko's macro at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433410/
   \frac{#1}{\ifnum#2<10\kern.25em#2\kern.25em\else#2\fi}}

\directlua{ dofile ( "aux.lua" ) } % load the Lua code from the external file

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.25} % for a less-cramped look...
\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{array}{@{} *{6}{L} @{}}
   \directlua{ makearray(6) } % 6: # of rows and columns in matrix
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Second, the Lua code. Save it to a separate file called `aux.lua`.

```lua
--[[
5 Lua functions:

-   is_prime(n)
      Test whether an integer is prime
-   find_prime_factors(n)
      Find and return all prime factors of an integer
         If n=1 or if n is a prime number: return n 
         Otherwise, return the true prime factors
-   fraction_simplify(a,b)
      Simplify a fraction expression, by removing
         common prime factors in num. and denom.
      Input:  numerator and denominator (integers)
      Output: fully simplified num. and denom.
-   print_simplified_fraction(a,b)
      Print the result of 'fraction_simplify'
-   makearray()
      Interface to the LaTeX code
]]--

function is_prime(n)
-- Sieve of Erathosthenes method
   for i = 2, n^0.5 do 
      if n%i == 0 then
         return false
      end
   end
   return true
end

function find_prime_factors ( n ) -- n: integer (>0)
   prime_factors = {}  -- Initialize a Lua "table"
   if ( n==1 or is_prime(n) ) then
        -- There's just one factor: 'n' itself
      table.insert ( prime_factors , n )
   else -- There are at least two (nontrivial) factors      
      while ( n>1 ) do
         for i=2, n do
            if n%i==0 then
               table.insert(prime_factors,i)
               n=n/i
               break
            end
         end
      end
   end
   return prime_factors
end

function fraction_simplify ( a , b ) 
-- It is assumed that both 'a' and 'b' are integers
   if a==b then -- the greatest simplfication!
      return 1 , 1 
   else
      -- assume numerator term smaller than denominator
      if a<b then 
         u=a
         v=b
      else 
         u=b
         v=a
      end

      -- Obtain the prime factors of 'u' and 'v'
      ufactors = find_prime_factors ( u )
      vfactors = find_prime_factors ( v )

      -- Replace matching prime factors with ones
      for i,j in ipairs ( ufactors ) do
         for k,l in ipairs ( vfactors ) do
            if (j>1 and j==l) then 
               ufactors[i]=1
               vfactors[k]=1            
               break
            end
         end
      end

      -- Compute the fully-simplified fractional terms
      ux=1; vx=1
      for _,j in ipairs ( ufactors ) do 
         ux = ux * j 
      end
      for _,l in ipairs ( vfactors ) do 
         vx = vx * l 
      end

      if a<b then
         return ux, vx
      else
         return vx, ux
      end
   end    
end

function print_simplified_fraction ( x , y )
   u , v = fraction_simplify ( x , y )
   if v==1 then -- Print just the numerator
      tex.sprint ( u ) 
   else
      tex.sprint ( "\\frac{"..u.."}{"..v.."}" )
   end
end

function makearray ( k ) -- k: number of rows and columns
   for i = 1, k do
      for j = 1, k do
         n, d = fraction_simplify ( i+j , 35)
         tex.sprint ( "("..i..","..j..")\\to\\mytwofrac{"..n.."}{"..d.."}" )
         if j<k then
            tex.sprint ( "&" )
         else
            tex.sprint ( "\\\\" )
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Some of the Lua functions above -- e.g., `is_prime` to test primality, and `find_prime_factors` to obtain the full list of prime factors of an integer -- may be useful for other settings as well.

Answer (score 4):

An `\xintFor` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintfrac, xinttools}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}

\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c@{}c@{}c}}
  \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq{1}{6}}\do {%
    \xintFor* #2 in {\xintSeq{1}{6}}\do
     {\xintifForFirst{}{&}%
       $(#1, #2)$
       &
       ${}\to{}$
       &
      % abuse the fact that they are few enough tokens
      % for the internal \numexpr to do the #1+#2
       $\displaystyle\xintFrac{\xintIrr{#1+#2/35}}$%
     }\\
  }%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]